# Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [adoptopenjdk-11]' in project '' with Processing

Tags: visual-studio-code, processing, classpath

I want to get processing 4 working in VSCode.
https://github.com/processing/processing4

Right not I get several errors that look like:

`Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [adoptopenjdk-11]' in project ''`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_11" project-jdk-name="adoptopenjdk-11" project-jdk-type="JavaSDK">
    <output url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/out" />
  </component>
</project>
```

It is not a maven or a graddle project, and I prefer to keep it that way if possible (e.g. using a `settings.json`).

Hope someone can help fix this error.

Comment: Are you trying to build Processing from source? Do you need to? Alpha 6 is available on the [downloads page](https://processing.org/download). Seems to work fine from VS Code after installing processing-java and the Processing Language extension.

Comment: Yeah, i want to make changes and need to use the debugger, so `ant run` is no option.